# In flutter project with Radio Button 'yes' value, input field not opening with saved value

Tags: forms, flutter, validation, dart, flutter-layout

I have created a form in my hybrid mobile application project with #flutter and #dart. This form has radio buttons and input fields. With radio button "yes" value, a container with input field should open. When I'm filling new application form it is being opened and saving data but after saving data when I'm returning to this form again to edit, those input fields are not showing. If I change the radio button value to "no" and again change it to "yes" then only the input fields are being opened again with previous saved data. What I'm doing wrong please tell me.

Please see the attached images for reference.

When filling new form input field is opening for "yes" value of radio button

[image]

After saving data in form when coming back to this same form to edit, input field is not showing with data

[image]

```dart
    int id = 0;
      static var orderID;
      var response;
      bool isStudyInUK = false;
      bool isRefusalForUK = false;
      bool isVisaRefusalForOC = false;
      PersonalDetailsModel pmodel; 

    //get passport visa details details
      static var passportNo;
      static var visarefusal;
      static var visaRefusalT;
      static var visaRefusalOther;
      static var visaRTOther;
      var passportVisaData;
      String url;
      getPassportVisaData() async {
        SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        //Return String
        String stringValue = prefs.getString('stringValue') ?? '';
        setState(() {
          orderID = stringValue;
        });
        print("Here is order id  " + orderID);
        if (orderID != "") {
          url =
              "https://mars.holmeseducation.group/webapi/findmulicpassportandvisa.php?order_id=$orderID";
        }
        print(url);
        var res = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull(url));
    
        var resBody = json.decode(res.body);
        print("Here is JSON body" + res.body);
    
        setState(() {
          passportVisaData = resBody;
          passportNo = passportVisaData[0]['payment_address_2'];
          visarefusal = passportVisaData[0]['apply_scholarship'];
          visaRefusalT = passportVisaData[0]['apply_scholarshiptext'];
          visaRefusalOther = passportVisaData[0]['visa_refusal_other'];
          visaRTOther = passportVisaData[0]['visa_refusal_othertext'];
          print(visa);
          print(country);
        });
        return passportVisaData;
      }

    //post passport & visa details
      Dio dio = new Dio();
    
      Future postData() async {
        String pathurl =
            "https://mars.holmeseducation.group/webapi/addsmulicpassportandvisa.php";
        }
    
        FormData formdata = new FormData.fromMap({
          "order_id": orderID,
          "passport": passportNo,
          "visarefusal": visarefusal,
          "visarefusaltext": visaRefusalT,
          "visa_refusal_other": visaRefusalOther,
          "visa_refusal_othertext'": visaRTOther,
        });
        response = await dio.post(pathurl, data: formdata);
        return response;
      }

    Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 12.0, bottom: 4, left: 12, right: 12),
                        child: Text(
                          'Have you ever had a visa refusal for any other country*',
                          style: style,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 12.0, bottom: 12.0, left: 12, right: 12),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 10,
                                  width: 25,
                                  child: Radio(
                                    value: 'Yes',
                                    groupValue: visaRefusalOther,
                                    onChanged: (val) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        visaRefusalOther = 'Yes';
                                        print(visaRefusalOther);
                                        isVisaRefusalForOC = true;
                                      });
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'Yes',
                                  style: style1,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 30,
                            ),
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 10,
                                  width: 25,
                                  child: Radio(
                                    value: 'No',
                                    groupValue: visaRefusalOther,
                                    onChanged: (val) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        visaRefusalOther = 'No';
                                        print(visaRefusalOther);
                                        isVisaRefusalForOC = false;
                                      });
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'No',
                                  style: style1,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      isVisaRefusalForOC
                          ? Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 10),
                              child: TextFormField(
                                onChanged: (avik) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    visaRTOther = avik;
                                  });
                                },
                                initialValue:
                                    (visaRTOther == null) ? '' : visaRTOther,
                                style: style,
                                validator: (value) {
                                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                    return 'Please enter some text';
                                  }
                                  return null;
                                },
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    contentPadding:
                                        EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 20.0, 80.0, 20.0),
                                    // labelText: 'Student Passport No.*',
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0))),
                              ),
                            )
                          : Container(),
```